# Import data from a closed workbook into an existing worksheet using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, import

I've got a piece of VBA code that will import a piece of data from another workbook into my open excel spreadsheet however, it won't import if into the sheet that I have already created. It wants to open a new sheet every time.

This is the code:

```
Sub ImportCurrentMonthData()
' Get workbook...
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim filter As String
Dim targetWorkbook As Workbook, wb As Workbook
Dim Ret As Variant

Set targetWorkbook = Application.ActiveWorkbook

' get the customer workbook
filter = "Excel files (*.xlsb),*.xlsb"
Caption = "Please Select an input file "
Ret = Application.GetOpenFilename(filter, , Caption)

If Ret = False Then Exit Sub

Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Ret)

wb.Sheets(1).Move After:=targetWorkbook.Sheets(targetWorkbook.Sheets.Count)

ActiveSheet.Name = "CurrentMonth"
```

I have a sheet called "CurrentMonth" already and I want to data to go into that spreadsheet. What do I need to change in the VBA code for this happen?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can activate the "CurrentMonth" Sheet: `wb.Worksheets("CurrentMonth").Activate` The question is how do you import the data?

Comment: Is `"CurrentMonth"` worksheet in your active workbook, or in the one you've just opened? If in your active workbook, **before opening** the second one, you should move the code immediately after `Set targetWorkbook = Application.ActiveWorkbook`. But where is your problem? Your code does not do anything. You practically name the active sheet of the opened workbook like "CurrentMonth". This is what you want doing?

Comment: @TomaszPaluch The "CurrentMonth" sheet is where I want the data to go. This VBA currently imports a selected spreadsheet into my active workbook but creates a new sheet called "CurrentMonth", I want it to import into a sheet already there instead of opening a new one.

Comment: @FaneDuru The code currently will open a closed workbook and import the data into a new sheet in the active workbook and call it "CurrentMonth". Instead I want it to import the data into the sheet that is already there. Does that make sense?

Comment: It doesn't... Try, please answer my questions. "Is `"CurrentMonth"` worksheet in your active workbook, or in the one you've just opened?". "But where is your problem?" Do you receive an error? The above code does not do anything, except opening the new workbook and rename its active sheet as "CurrentMonth", "Is this what you want doing?"

Comment: So basically, you need to open the source workbook, activate the source sheet, copy the desired range (cells), activate your target sheet and paste the data (values). Using the `.Copy` and `.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues` methods of `Range`.

Comment: @FaneDuru It does. it's doing that right now. "CurrentMonth" is not currently in any workbook. It appears once the code is run, with the data from the closed workbook in it. I want it to already be there, but blank, and then the code imports the data from a closed workbook that I choose as part of the code. There is no current error, apart from my want to change a slight part of it. But trust me, the code is doing something.

Comment: @TomaszPaluch What I want to do is have a button that someone will push, a dialog box will open to select the workbook that they wish to import, and then the data will appear on the sheet called "CurrentMonth", the code currently does all this but creates a new sheet within the active workbook and calls it "CurrentMonth". I want that sheet to already be there, and be blank, until the data is imported. The code won't do that as it is erroring out telling me that the sheet already existed, and it wants to create a new one.

Comment: The code **does not create any new sheet**! It open the workbook, moves its first sheet after the last one, and **name the active sheet** "CurrentMonth". If you do not need this pseudo new sheet, just comment the last line `'ActiveSheet.Name = "CurrentMonth"`. Your code does not do anything in terms of copying data from some sheet to another sheet. It only opens a workbook and does what I explain. It does not create any new sheet, too.

Comment: Okay, so you have a destination sheet called "CurrentMonth". In the beginning of your procedure, you can put something like this: `Worksheets("CurrentMonth").Activate
Worksheets("CurrentMonth").Range("A1:C10").ClearContents` - this will delete the data from range A1:C10

Comment: @FaneDuru have you placed the code into VBA within excel and seen what it has done? because right now in excel for me, **it is** bringing in data from a closed spreadsheet and creating a new worksheet within my active workbook. I actually got it from a website that I can link. Please test this, and then tell me it is doing nothing.

Comment: No need of any test. I can red such a simple code. If you imagine that the vode reads from a closed workbook, this is wrong. It omly opens the workbook and YOU read its content...

Comment: @FaneDuru If you had tested it, then you would realise that you are wrong. If you're not actually wanting to help, please refrain from commenting further. SOURCE: https://www.excelhow.net/how-to-import-data-from-another-workbook-in-excel.html#:~:text=Just%20do%20the%20following%20steps:,code%20into%20the%20code%20window.

Comment: I was asking some questions in order to lelp you to copy from the open workbook in your existing one. Since yuo do not understand elementary things, I abandon this task. I wish you a good day! You maybe will find somebody more patient to understand something from your way of explaining...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want top copy the data to an existing sheet....

```
Sub ImportCurrentMonthData()

    ' Get workbook...
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim filter As String
    Dim targetWorkbook As Workbook, wb As Workbook
    Dim Ret As Variant

    Set targetWorkbook = Application.ActiveWorkbook 'ThisWorkbook?

    ' get the customer workbook
    filter = "Excel files (*.xlsb),*.xlsb"
    Caption = "Please Select an input file "
    Ret = Application.GetOpenFilename(filter, , Caption)

    If Ret = False Then Exit Sub

    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Ret)

    wb.Sheets(1).Usedrange.Copy targetWorkbook.Sheets("CurrentMonth").Range("A1")
```

Comment: Thanks but this is now coming up with the error code '1004' - Application-defined or object-defined error. When i push debug, it highlights the last sentence.

Comment: Sorry bad copy/paste from your posted code. Fixed now

Comment: That works! Thank you, last request if you can be so kind. Is there anyway to do it so that it doesn't open the closed workbook? So if it imports the data only? It's probably part of my own code that needs to be changed but I can't think of it.

Comment: You have to open the file if you want to copy the data.  If your data is structured like a table then you could maybe use SQL to query the worksheet but that's more complex than just open/copy/close.

Comment: Thank for your answer, is there any way to close the spreadsheet once it is copied as part of the VBA?

Comment: `wb.Close False`